# Android - Application hangs when json string is not valid or is empty

Tags: java, android, json

this is a function that get **json** string and parse it. I used **try catch** and also checked that if response is **empty** or **null** method should return null. Also I have a condition when I used this method that if method returned null I will notify to user and close this activity and do other thing.

But when I run application and json is not valid (is null , empty or not json formatted) application hangs and only I see SplashScreen.

```
public List<UpdateItemsModel> GetAllAddItems(String response)
{
    try
    {
        if(response == null || response == "")
        {
            return null;
        }
        List<UpdateItemsModel> result = new ArrayList<UpdateItemsModel>();
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray add = null;;
        JSONObject temp = null;
        JSONObject values = null;
        UpdateItemsModel item = null;
        Course course = null;
        if(json.has("add"))
        {
            add = json.getJSONArray("add");
        }

        if(add != null){
            for(int i=0;i<add.length();i++)
            {
                //add function here
                temp = add.getJSONObject(i);
                if(temp.getString("tableName").equals("tbl_course"))
                {
                    values = temp.getJSONObject("values");
                    course = new Course();
                    course.setChapterId(values.getInt("chapter_id"));
                    course.setFavorite(values.getBoolean("favorite"));
                    course.setId(values.getInt("id"));
                    course.setRead(values.getBoolean("read"));
                    course.setText(values.getString("text"));
                    course.setTitle(values.getString("title"));

                    item = new UpdateItemsModel();
                    item.setCourse(course);

                    result.add(item);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        HandleExceptions.ReportErrorToServer(e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

log result :

```
08-22 08:45:58.941: I/ActivityManager(472): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000     cmp=com.example.book/.SplashActivity} from pid 5030
08-22 08:45:58.953: W/audio_hw_primary(114): out_write() limiting sleep time 34149 to 23219
08-22 08:45:58.977: W/audio_hw_primary(114): out_write() limiting sleep time 35759 to 23219
08-22 08:45:59.001: W/audio_hw_primary(114): out_write() limiting sleep time 27369 to 23219
08-22 08:45:59.085: D/dalvikvm(472): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1966K, 33% free 11025K/16392K, paused 26ms, total 27ms
08-22 08:45:59.193: D/dalvikvm(14508): Late-enabling CheckJNI
08-22 08:45:59.197: I/ActivityManager(472): Start proc com.example.book for activity com.example.book/.SplashActivity: pid=14508 uid=10049 gids={50049, 3003, 1028}
08-22 08:45:59.505: D/libEGL(14508): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
08-22 08:45:59.505: D/(14508): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8ff7e08, tid 14508
08-22 08:45:59.537: D/libEGL(14508): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
08-22 08:45:59.537: D/libEGL(14508): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
08-22 08:45:59.681: W/EGL_genymotion(14508): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-22 08:45:59.685: E/OpenGLRenderer(14508): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
08-22 08:45:59.693: E/OpenGLRenderer(14508): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
08-22 08:45:59.697: D/OpenGLRenderer(14508): Enabling debug mode 0
08-22 08:45:59.885: I/ActivityManager(472): Displayed com.example.book/.SplashActivity: +754ms
08-22 08:46:00.429: W/TelephonyManager(14508): Overriding DeviceId with 000000000000000
```

Comment: Do you have the error log? This could be helpful

Comment: Is the app working with a valid JSON? What happens if you try to return a empty list instead of null?

Comment: @Patrick app works if json be valid , same result for empty or null or not valid string

Comment: @BrunoFranco log added

Comment: @mmlooloo when I return null, application has same problem, so I checked it again and I found that the issue is on another method, thank you , you can post an answer and I'll vote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your logic of SplashScreen has some issues. just add `return null;` before try and see whats going on.

also you must check equality of string in this way:

```
response.equals("");
```

`response == something` checks references of those strings not the value of them, if those strings point to the same location the result is true else is false. those string may references to two different location but may have equal value like this:

```
String s1 = "1223";

String s2 = "1223";

s1==s2  // returns false

s1.equals(s2) // returns true
```

Comment: first section of your answer helped me fix the issue, thank you so much ;)